# The target "PreLinkEvent" does not exist in VS2015 C++ project

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I created a clean C++ DLL project in VS2015 and added C (not CPP, but C) source file containing this:

```
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

and got:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1180,11): error MSB4057: The target "PreLinkEvent" does not exist in the project.**

where did it come from?

Comment: looks line something is wrong with my VS, because the projects builds successfully on another machine.

Comment: It is a "hello world" kind of problem.  The target is defined in the C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets file.  Have a look at it, don't be surprised if the file look corrupted or completely empty.  You need to check the health of the disk drive, at least run chkdsk, reinstall VS.

Comment: yes, looks like my disk on Hyper-V virtual machine was corrupted.